# NodeJS export async variable with module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have 2 files in a nodejs app:

**export.js** (reads a file line by line and saves it into an array)

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('test.txt')
});
var file_lines = [];

onFinish(function(result) {
    module.exports = result;
});

function onFinish(callback){
    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

        file_lines.push(line);

    }).on('close', function() {
        callback(file_lines);
    })
};
```

and **app.js** (should get the exported values so I can play with it in here)

```
var a = require("./export");

console.log(a);
```

As you can see in the **export.js** I've used an async callback so it will save the data, but I think I'll need another async callback in the **app.js** file. What would be the best way to achieve this?

P.S. I realized that the async call for the **export.js** file isn't necessary. Here is the new version:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('test.txt')
});
var file_lines = [];

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

    file_lines.push(line);

}).on('close', function() {
    module.exports = file_lines;
    console.log(file_lines);
})
```

But again, my question will be, how would I get the values in the a variable in the **app.js** file?

Comment: Perhaps a bit too pragmatic, but why not just read `test.txt` synchronously, split the contents into lines, and export those?

Comment: Yeah, this should work also. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('test.txt')
});
var file_lines = [];

module.exports = function onFinish(callback){
    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

        file_lines.push(line);

    }).on('close', function() {
        callback(file_lines);
    })
};
```

and then

```
var a = require("./export");

a(function(data){ console.log(data) })
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you add some comments for explanation for other readers? :)

Comment: I don't know how explain it, it's very simple. Just export of function with callback argument.

Comment: @Maxx there are certainly things you can explain here, i.e. why there is a problem with trying to synchronously export the result of an async function and how exporting a function taking a callback works around that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a callback, you can also export a **promise**:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('test.txt')
});

module.exports = function (user) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var file_lines = [];

        lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

        file_lines.push(line);

        }).on('close', function() {
            resolve(file_lines);
        })

    })
}
```

Then use it nicely, like this:

```
read_lines = require('line_reader')

read_lines()
    .then(function (lines) {
        // lines are already read here
    })
```

to get the Promise, you can install bluebird with `npm i bluebird`

Answer (score 0):

You can export function `lineReader` and set `onFinish` as callback function where `console.log` can write in